# Repeated use of setTimeout in JavaScript refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, html, function, recursion

I am in the process of building a basic timer using HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.

Currently the timer accepts minutes and seconds as output and once the timer is done, the user is alerted. There is no way of seeing progress at the moment but I do plan on adding it once I've solved my problem.

When the start button is clicked, the JavaScript function startTimer is called, which calculates at what time (hours, minutes, seconds) the timer will finish and stores these values in an array. If one of the values goes past it's maximum (eg seconds goes past 59) then the maximum will be subtracted and 1 will be passed onto the next item in the array (in my example, minutes). Another function, updateTime, is called, with the finish time array passed as a parameter.

updateTime gets the current hours, minutes, and seconds and stores them in an array, before comparing them to the finish array. If they are equal, the timer must be finished, so the user is alerted the time is up and that is that. If they aren't equal, setTimeout is called to execute updateTime again passing in the finish time after 1000 milliseconds (1 second).

When I run my webpage and specify a time and click start, the page simply refreshes.

**Code:**

timer.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head lang="en">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Timer</title>
        <script src="script.js"></script> 
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <label for="minutes" id="minutes-label">Minutes</label>
            <input id="minutes" type="number" min="0" max="59" value="0"/>
            <label for="seconds" id="seconds-label">Seconds</label>
            <input id="seconds" type="number" min="0" max="59" value="0"/>
            <br></br>
                
            <button onclick="startTimer()">Start</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
function updateTime(f) {
    let d = new Date();
    let current = [d.getSeconds(),d.getMinutes(),d.getHours()];

    if (current === f) {
        alert("Time is up!");   
    }
    else {
        setTimeout(updateTime,1000,f);
    }
}

function startTimer() {
    let increaseSecs = parseInt(document.getElementById("seconds").value);
    let increaseMins = parseInt(document.getElementById("minutes").value);

    let d = new Date();
    let finish = [d.getSeconds()+increaseSecs,d.getMinutes()+increaseMins,d.getHours()];
    if (finish[0] >= 60) {
        finish[0] -= 60;
        finish[1] += 1;
    }

    if (finish[1] >= 60) {
        finish[1] -= 60;
        finish[2] += 1;
    }

    updateTime(finish);
}
```

The updateTime function should be executed every second until the current and finish arrays match, indicating the time is up, at which point the user is alerted that the timer has finished.

If I add console.log each time the current array is compared to the finish array, the log is written to once before the page refreshes.

I've also replaced setTimeout with setInterval but the problem remains.

Comment: Clicking the `<button>` submits the form on the page. Which refreshes the page. Don't have a form or prevent its submission.

Comment: You can add `type="button"` to the `<button>` to make it not submit, or prevent the default action when listening for the form submit for a more global solution. (Or just get rid of the form tags as VLAZ suggested.)

Comment: `<button type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the people who commented telling me the problem was that my start button was set to submit by default. Indeed, after changing the button type to "button", the page no longer refreshed. However, nothing happened so I began to add some console.log lines to see the boolean result of my if statements and as it turns out, JavaScript cannot compare arrays using the equality operator (===), and instead must compare each item of the array individually. To solve this problem, I added in an extra function.

```
function arrayIsEqual(arr1,arr2) {
    let equal = true;
    for (let i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
        if (arr1[i] !== arr2[i]) {
            equal = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return equal;
}
```

Implementing this into my if statement, I successfully ran the timer multiple times, trying different minutes and seconds combinations.